# Select item predictions from a prediction DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, prediction, recommendation-engine

I am very new to DataScience/Pandas in general. I mainly followed [this guide](https://beckernick.github.io/matrix-factorization-recommender/) about recommender systems.

The main difference I have is that my movie data starts out from one table, and I want to find the most similar movies to a specific movie from that list.

Initial Data Frame looks like:
[image]

Which I then convert to a sparse Data Frame where a user's ratings for each movie can be shown:

```
rating_with_totalRatingCount = rating_with_totalRatingCount.drop_duplicates(['userID', 'movieTitle'])
ratingPivot = rating_with_totalRatingCount.pivot(index = 'movieTitle', columns = 'userID', values = 'userRatingScore').fillna(0).T
```

[image]

And lastly I apply the dot product rule to get the predictions Data Frame:

```
U, sigma, Vt = svds(ratingPivot, k = 50)

sigma = np.diag(sigma)

all_user_predicted_ratings = np.dot(np.dot(U, sigma), Vt) + user_ratings_mean.values.reshape(-1, 1)
preds_df = pd.DataFrame(all_user_predicted_ratings, columns = ratingPivot.columns)
```

[image]

My question is, how can I use this prediction Data Frame to give someone the movies most similar to a specific movie in Python?

Answer (score 2):

So, in theory, this is how it works -

1. You first create what is called a Utility matrix. This utility matrix is a (user X item) size matrix (in your case you created it with a pivot). The utility matrix can have different values as measures. For, example it could be the movie rating
2. The utility matrix can usually have a lot of null values (if a user has not viewed a movie, then their rating for that movie would not exist)
3. Now you handle that by re-constructing the Utility matrix by estimating the ratings itself using a matrix decomposition method. Basically, using the existing ratings as training data to find out which matrices that when multiplied together minimize the loss (i.e the difference between the actual rating and the predicted rating). Doing so estimates ratings that didn't exist in the training data.
4. Now that you have estimated a utility matrix (user x item), all you have to do is get to an item-item similarity matrix (item x item) or a user-user similarity matrix (user x user). You can do this by taking a dot product of the (item x user), which is the transpose of the reconstructed utility matrix, with (user x item) matrix. This would result in an (item x item) similarity matrix (a better way is to take a cosine similarity as its normalized).
5. Once you have taken the dot product, take a single item (row in the similarity matrix) and find the top 10 values to get the top 10 most similar items.
6. The 'similarity' is based on what measure you used in the utility matrix in the first place, in this case, ratings.